# How do I select an element with special characters in the ID?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a page with a grid containing a lot if input with "strange names" to simulate an array:

```
 <input type="text" id="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" name="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" class="{validate: {required:true}}" value="@item.Descrizione" />
```

How can I set the value of these inputs with jQuery, specifically, how would I select them? I tried in a lot of ways but nothing works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that brackets have special meaning in CSS (as attribute selectors) and dots do too, as class selectors. Try [`$.escapeSelector`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/):

```
$('#' + $.escapeSelector('Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione'))
```

This will escape the selector so the special characters don't affect the selection. You could also try using an attribute selector and wrapping that in quotes:

```
$('[id="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione"]')
```

This will literally match that ID and won't treat any of the special characters as special characters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `[`, `]`, `@` and `.` characters in the `id` selector. To do that, use `\\` like this:

```js
var val = $('#Punteggi\\[\\@counter\\]\\.Descrizione').val();

console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" name="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" class="{validate: {required:true}}" value="@item.Descrizione" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked and answered, more developments have been made in the DOM and CSSOM space to make this easier, both for jQuery users, and for non-jQuery users. I present [`CSS.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape):

In jQuery:

```js
var id = "Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione";
var selector = `#${CSS.escape(id)}`;
var val = $(selector).val();

console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" name="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" class="{validate: {required:true}}" value="@item.Descrizione" />
```

Without jQuery:

```js
var id = "Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione";
var selector = `#${CSS.escape(id)}`;
var val = document.querySelector(selector).value;

console.log(val);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" name="Punteggi[@counter].Descrizione" class="{validate: {required:true}}" value="@item.Descrizione" />
```