# How to check radio input status when name attribute is array type?

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="raio-group require">
    <input class="fp_radio" type="radio" name="fp_tax_category[]" value="9">ইসলাম ও জীবন
    <br>
    <input class="fp_radio" type="radio" name="fp_tax_category[]" value="7">কবিতা
    <br>
    <input class="fp_radio" type="radio" name="fp_tax_category[]" value="1">গল্প
    <br>
    <input class="fp_radio" type="radio" name="fp_tax_category[]" value="11">ট্রিপস &amp; ট্রিকস
    <br>
    <input class="fp_radio" type="radio" name="fp_tax_category[]" value="8">প্রযুক্তি
    <br>
    <input class="fp_radio" type="radio" name="fp_tax_category[]" value="10">সাম্প্রতিক বিষয়
    <br>
</div>
```

jquer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.require').bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event){
        THIS = $(this);
        validate();

        if(no_error_remaining())
            $('.common-success-msg').show();

    });

});
function validate(){

    if(is_empty())
        set_warning();
    else
        unset_warning();
}
function is_empty(){

    if(THIS.hasClass('raio-group'))
        return radio_is_unchecked();    
    else if(THIS.hasClass('input-group'))
        return is_input_group_not_set();
    else if(THIS.hasClass('wp-editor-area')){
        return editor_content_is_empty('frontier_post_content');
    }
    else
        return is_value_not_set();
}

function radio_is_unchecked(){

    var name = THIS.find("input").attr("name");

    if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This code was working fine while radio type input name attribute was: fp_tax_ctegory. I am in a situation to use fp_tax_ctegory as name. Now I am getting the following error:  `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:radio[name=fp_tax_category[]]:checked` This error say all by itself. I got my fault. But how can I resolve this issue keeping the fp_tax_category[] instead of fp_tax_category?

Comment: As you can tell `[` and `]` are reserved characters for the selector operation. You need to explicitly say that it's a string by using `$("input:radio[name='"+name+"']:checked")` as a selector, note the additional apostrophe. [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900544/how-do-i-select-an-element-with-special-characters-in-the-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `THIS` contains the `class="raio-group require">` element , you can rewrite the `radio_is_unchecked` function:

```
function radio_is_unchecked(){
    return THIS.find('input:checked').length >= 0;
}
```

If you want to keep the function as it is, you'll have to espace the `[]` characters with `\` to fix the css selector.

Comment: if I have multiple group, then it works perfectly? meaning is THIS.find('input:checked') deal with nearest radio inputs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a new version of JQuery (version >= 3.0), you can use `$.escapeSelector( "fp_tax_category[]" );`

Here is the code to change :

```
function radio_is_unchecked(){

    var name = THIS.find("input").attr("name");
    // Here is the change 
    if($("input:radio[name="+$.escapeSelector( name )+"]:checked").length == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name different class for different group (ex group1) of radio buttons.

```
<div class="raio-group require">
    <input class="fp_radio group1" type="radio" name="fp_tax_category[]" value="9">
```

Then you can modify the function like this

```
function radio_is_unchecked(){
    return THIS.find('.group1:checked').length >= 0;
}
```