# How to get value with jquery from complex input name

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, input

Here's my case:

I'm trying to get value from form's input that has `name="data[type][answer]"`, something like:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="data[type][answer]" value="Hello from Space">
</form>
```

So, my code for function should look like:

```
 function queryForm(key) {
   return $('#form input[name=' + key + ']').val();
 }
```

I'm getting `input[name=order[type][answer]]` which is not working and I'm aware why.

Is there a way how to write this thing differently or is there any other way how to get the value? By the way, I need the name exactly in this form: `name="data[type][answer]"`

Any advice or solution would be nice!

Comment: Try this `function queryForm(key) {
   return $('#form input[name=' + key + ']')[0].val();
 }`

Comment: @Stranger your solution raises a script error, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select an element with special characters in the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900544/how-do-i-select-an-element-with-special-characters-in-the-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you just need to do is ...

```
function queryForm(key) {
   return $('#form input[name="' + key + '"]').val();
}
```

note the double quote (") around key.

Answer (score 1):

You just need quotes around the value for `name`. Then you have to select the first result from the returned and wrap it again with jquery to be able to call `.val()`:

```js
function queryForm(key) {
    return $("#form input[name='" + key + "']").first()
      .val();
}
 
console.log(queryForm('data[type][answer]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form id="form" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" name="data[type][answer]" value="Hello from Space">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: A couple of tips to make this a little easier: Use double quotes instead of escaping single quotes. Use `.first()` instead of using `[0]` and wrapping the result with another jQuery call.