# Table exists but returns 0 when checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an HTML table with a particular id but when I try to check if it exists or not it returns `0`.

```
<table border = "1px"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="Evolución_Depósitos_a_Plazo_+_Restringidos" %> style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0%;font-size:12px;">
  <thead>
    <td align="center" colspan="17">Evolución_Depósitos_a_Plazo_+_Restringidos</td>
    <tr>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td align="center" colspan="13">Evolución Tasa de Morosidad </td>
      <td align="center" colspan="3">Variacion %</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I have used this code to check whether if it exists: 
    $('table#Evolución_Depósitos_a_Plazo_+_Restringidos').length

However this returns `0`. Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select an element with special characters in the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900544/how-do-i-select-an-element-with-special-characters-in-the-id)

Comment: Don't use such chars in an id. No '+' or '/' or whatever. Only ASCII literals, '_' and '-'  is best practice. Ids should never start with a number or '-'  due to CSS issues for some old browsers.

Comment: Thank you but I was forced to use this because it is dynamically generated and the id served a purpose that's why. It is working fine with escaping characters it is ok right ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes and I have selected that as the answer. I didn't know that '+' was a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the `+` character in the selector which has a [special meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator). You need to escape it using `\\`.

Also note that your HTML is invalid. The first `td` needs to be within a `tr`.

```js
console.log($('table#Evolución_Depósitos_a_Plazo_\\+_Restringidos').length);
```

```css
table {
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="Evolución_Depósitos_a_Plazo_+_Restringidos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="17">Evolución_Depósitos_a_Plazo_+_Restringidos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td align="center" colspan="13">Evolución Tasa de Morosidad </td>
      <td align="center" colspan="3">Variacion %</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```