# jquery Syntax error, unrecognized expression when class name is encrypted and contain special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var className  = "order_enc_YUluWTo6ODA4OTczNjQ3MjAzOTc0OA%3D%3D";
$('input:checkbox.' + className).each(function() {
            (this.checked ? arr.push($(this).val()) : "");
        });
```

having encrypted class name but when trying to run loop getting error
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checkbox.order_enc_YUluWTo6ODA4OTczNjQ3MjAzOTc0OA%3D%3D

tried single double quots but with no success.

Comment: `.order_enc_YUluWTo6ODA4OTczNjQ3MjAzOTc0OA%3D%3D` is not a valid selector.

Comment: You can't have a `%` or an `=` (`%3D`) in a name of a class.... I think.

Comment: Why are you encrypting class names?!? Things like class names should never have data in them worth encrypting in the first place. Use an index or some other non-identifying information that you can link back to your secure information in a more secure context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select an element with special characters in the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900544/how-do-i-select-an-element-with-special-characters-in-the-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
<input type="checkbox" class="order_enc_YUluWTo6ODA4OTczNjQ3MjAzOTc0OA%3D%3D" value="true">

var className  = "order_enc_YUluWTo6ODA4OTczNjQ3MjAzOTc0OA%3D%3D";
$('input:checkbox[class="'+className+'"]').each(function() {
    (this.checked ? arr.push($(this).val()) : "");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Abdo-Host , it's working perfectly fine

Comment: @SyedmahdiRaza You are welcome :)

Answer (score -3):

```
    // Connect in HTML file the src for the CryptoJs Lib
 /* <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"> 
 </script> */
 let className  = "order_enc_YUluWTo6ODA4OTczNjQ3MjAzOTc0OA%3D%3D";
 let decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(className,'Secure className');
 let decryptToString = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
 $('input' + decryptToString).each(function() {
        ($(this).checked ? arr.push($(this).val()) : "");
        console.log($(this).val())
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).